# Seeing `%s` instead of specific properties in react error messages in electron project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron

All the React errors and warnings in my electron project look like this:

```
"Warning: Invalid event handler property `%s`. Did you mean `%s`?%s", source: webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js? (506)
```

What would be causing this? Is something misconfigured? I'm not sure what to change. Tagged this four ways because I'm not sure where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you check the actual dev tools instead of the console, the issue isn't present there. Best I found.